# C# Programmatically opening a cmd.exe and writing a command into console when UseShellExecute is true

Tags: c#, cmd, command-line, selenium-edgedriver

I've tried the snippet of code:

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
info.UseShellExecute = true;
info.Verb = "runas";
p.StartInfo = info;
p.Start();

using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
{
    if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
    {
        sw.WriteLine("DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0");
    }
}
```

It successfully opens up a command prompt with administrative privileges, but I can't seem to write into it use streamwriter. I know that this is because I don't have RedirectStandardInput set to true. If I do set this to true, I am able to write but my console loses its elevated privileges. My question is how can I write a command into the console when UseShellExecute is true?

Comment: If your process doesn't have an administrative user token, there's no way it can write to a process that *does* have an administrative user token. If it could, UAC would be broken and pointless.

Comment: Makes sense. What approach would you propose?

Comment: Run your process as administrator first. If your code works *without* elevating cmd.exe, that's the only way you can do it *with* elevating it.

Comment: Have you tried passing the command to run in the CMD window using `cmd.exe`'s `/k` option (instead of using a stream).  This, of course, won't solve your UAC issue

Comment: I've included a manifest in my project with <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" /> but it doesn't seem to be taking effect